How to set up standard port 80 external access for a Kubernetes application using Gateway API?
I'm new to Kubernetes and haven't used Ingress. I noticed that Ingress is no longer being updated, according to the documentation, so I'm not planning to use it. Instead, I'm considering using the Gateway API. My question is: How can I enable external access through a standard port like http://example.com/ (port 80)?
I'm unsure which component should provide the external entry point for port 80. While I've seen some tutorials where the Gateway's listener is set to port 80, it seems to be an internal port. For example, in this NGINX Gateway Fabric documentation (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-gateway-fabric/how-to/traffic-management/routing-traffic-to-your-app/), the external access port is a high-numbered NodePort, which doesn't seem elegant.
I'm quite confused about how to elegantly implement standard port 80 external access. I've been stuck on this issue for a while and would greatly appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

If you look at the docs port 80 here is an external port:
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: cafe
spec:
  gatewayClassName: nginx
  listeners:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: HTTP
EOF

And here is an internal service port within Kubernetes (backend):
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: coffee
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: cafe
  hostnames:
  - "cafe.example.com"
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /
    backendRefs:
    - name: coffee
      port: 80
EOF

This works in the same fashion as an Ingress resource. However, like you mentioned the Gateway API is the replacing it.

Thank you very much for your response. Although in that example, I cannot access through port 80, high-numbered ports are accessible. I will look into it further, thank you.

You may have restriction on port 80 (ports below 1024: https://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access) .  Are you doing any port forwarding at all?

I think I have not done any port forwarding, just installed k8s on the machine.

You may have some firewall rules?
